# Attaching strace to 100% CPU Apache process - output

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, ubuntu, strace

I am having a problem with Apache2 spawning processes that use 100% CPU.

Attaching strace to one of such processes produces no output sometimes and sometimes gives this:

```
2672  17:18:07 poll([{fd=14, events=POLLIN|POLLPRI}], 1, 0) = 0 (Timeout)
2672  17:18:07 write(14, "\236\3\0\0\3SELECT FLOOR(((price_index."..., 930) = 930
2672  17:18:07 read(14, "\1\0\0\1\2\33\0\0\2\3def\0\0\0\5range\0\f?\0\r\0\0\0\10\0"..., 16384) = 85
```

I would be grateful for any ideas as to interpreting the above.

Comment: Are you running php? Is the strace made when the proces was using 100% CPU? What is recorded in the access log at the same time? Do you have an apache status page? Are you using compression, keep-alive, caching, mysql?

Comment: Yes, Magento to be precise. Yes, strace is being attached while the process is at 100% CPU.

Comment: Yes to MySQL, yes to keep-alive, no errors in log files, no compression. Status is disabled but I'll try it now. I now have a sneaking suspicion that this is related to a recent security update to Apache (USN-1259-1)

Comment: It is interesting also the access log. Try to find out for which URL apache will use 100% CPU for long time (5 seconds for a response should be considered long these days).

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing crime. From the your output some script (mb php) create sql qury to db.
You can crete much more info with using -s flag. E.g:

```
strace -pPID -s1024 > /tmp/mysql.pid.strace 2>&1
```